# Perl Print regex matches from an array to a html <td>

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have the following code in perl which is outputting each value of an array to a new HTML table cell and table row

```
print "<tr><td>$_<br/></td></tr>\n" for @fruitArray;
```

The contents of the array are as follows:

```
APPLE|0
ORANGE|0
PEAR|1
GRAPE|0
TOMATO|1
```

I want to print everything before the | in the first table cell and then everything after the | in a second table cell on that row

I presume I need to use regex something like:

```
/([|])\w+/
```

Just unsure on the exact syntax of printing this in one line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really very simple

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data = qw/
    APPLE|0
    ORANGE|0
    PEAR|1
    GRAPE|0
    TOMATO|1
/;

print "<table>\n";
printf "    <tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", split /\|/ for @data;
print "</table>\n";
```

#### output

```
<table>
    <tr><td>APPLE</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ORANGE</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>PEAR</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>GRAPE</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>TOMATO</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my @names = ("APPLE|0", "ORANGE|0", "PEAR|1", "GRAPE|0", "TOMATO|1");

foreach my $n (@names) {
while ($n =~ m/(.*?)\|(\d+)/g) {
        print "<tr><td>$1<br/></td></tr>\n";
        print "<tr><td>$2<br/></td></tr>\n";
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
<tr><td>APPLE<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>0<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>ORANGE<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>0<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>PEAR<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>1<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>GRAPE<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>0<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>TOMATO<br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>1<br/></td></tr>
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/QPOvzd